# building and using jhears usind maven2

Tags: java, ubuntu, maven-2

I am trying to use a sound fingerprint library these days and from as a result of lots of google-ing I found jhears is something I should try.

follow the steps as described in the [install.txt](https://www.gitorious.org/jhears/jhears/source/750ae3971d422e367dc137aefc032a7cbe2d97b1%3aINSTALL.txt#L17) but it keep giving me the error;

> Project ID: null:jersey-server:bundle:null
>
> Reason: Cannot find parent: com.sun.jersey:jersey-project for project:
>   null:jersey-server:bundle:null for project
>   null:jersey-server:bundle:null

also searched the error but could not find any thing to fix it. As I understand marven cannot locate the jersey-project. as this is a old project (no updates for 3 years) this is really possible.

how can fix this issue i tried removing `repositories` tag also tried to change version for the project. but did not work.

I am pretty sure I ll face similar problems as this is only the first step. Do you know a permanent solution for this.

Here you can the [pom.xml](https://www.gitorious.org/jhears/jhears/source/750ae3971d422e367dc137aefc032a7cbe2d97b1%3aexternal/jersey-pico/pom.xml) file for the build. This is the second step in the installation manual.

Comment: Does your jersey jar gets downloaded ?

Comment: Can we see your pom.xml ?

Comment: Itachi (i like using it), just edited the question. Thanks.

Comment: I was able to run this on OS X 10.9.1 and it worked cleanly for me. Which step is it throwing that error on? The jersey-pico `mvn clean install`? I had `jersey-server` 1.4 installed locally before this build so it didn't have remotely fetch it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think it may be because of wrong cache previously downloaded by maven. try clearing local cache of maven by following way:

```
rm -rf ~/.m2/repository/com/sun/jersey
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you upgrade your jersey server dependency.  when I searched for the 1.4 version pom, I got this file http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-server/1.4/jersey-server-1.4.pom.   It does not look like any pom I have ever seen and that may be source of your trouble.

I also noticed that the 1.4 version is fairly old.  1.18 is the current release version.